# Parse a plist in android and display data in the list view

Tags: android, parsing, plist

I am beginner in android, my requirement is to parse a plist file and display its result in the  list view.

List view contains an icon image, Name of the icon and an image button which shows price to buy that icon.

I am struggling from few days on this, can anybody let me know the solution?

Thanks in advance,

Tejaswi Marakini

Comment: do you update your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As plist contains xml, you should use xml parser for that. User SAX or Pull parser. Use custom list adapter to show the content in ListView

Have a look on these examples

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/04/simple-rss-reader-in-listview.html

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/